# Can't open the custom dialog box using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, modal-dialog

I'm trying to create a custom dialog using jQuery Core.

```html
<button id="finish" value="Finish">Finish</button>
<dialog id="confirm-finish">
    <p>Confirm to end test</p>
    <span>
        <button value="y">Yes</button>
        <button value="n">No</button>
    </span>
</dialog>
```

```
$("#finish").click(function(){
    $("confirm-finish").dialog('open');
});
```

neither the dialog() nor the modal() function is working here

I'm expecting some function that can open the dialog box using core jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open dialog box there is no inbuilt function.

You need to add open attribute show dialog box

```
$("#confirm-finish").attr('open','');
```

To hide it again you have to call

```
$("#confirm-finish").removeAttr('open');
```

Modal is different thing you need to use bootstrap library for it and it is better to use modal as it provides better options to manage with better UI.